# How to validate and submit N number of input fields with various Type to Rest Service?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, backbone.js

I am creating a dynamic HTML form with N number of input fields and their input types also varies. I need to validate all fields before submit the form data to Rest Service in key value format. On form button click i am doing this

```
var data;
var submit = 0;
var formField = [];
var i = 0;
$('form input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length == "0") {
                    submit = 1;
            } else {
                    formField[i] = $(this).val();
            }
i++;
            });
    if (submit == 0) { 
//if submit == 0 submit the form

data = {"credentialFields[0].value" : formField[0],
        "credentialFields[1].value" : formField[1],
        "credentialFields[2].value" : formField[2],     
    };
```

There i have problem like i am not able to use HTML5 native validation because i am not using button type="submit" and i am not able to validate input types like radio, checkbox and select. please suggest me the best solution for this problem.

Comment: What kind of validation do you need to do for these fields, and why can't you use jQuery for getting their values to check?

Comment: if HTML5 validation is possible that's fine or manual validation also fine. I am using the Jquery to get fields value, please have a look again.

Comment: i find the way but still am not able to parse the form data into json object    $('form').submit(function(event){
        // cancels the form submission
        event.preventDefault();
        // SUBMIT THE FORM
    });

Comment: You don't say anything about the validation you need to do, so I have no idea what kind of help you expect, since you already know how to get the data to be validated. Now you talk about parsing data into a JSON object, which had nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: My question is still same i asked how to validate N number of fields with different input type and then passing their values to Rest Service using JSON object in above format. Now i know How to validate but still don't have idea to get their values in JSON object after validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <form id="myForm" method="POST">
        <textarea name='area2' required>some textarea</textarea>
        <input type='text' name='text1' required />
        <input type='text' name='text2' value='some text' required />
        <input type='radio' name='radio' value='radio1' required/>
        <input type='radio' name='radio' value='radio2' required/>
        <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox1' value='checkbox1' required/>
        <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox2' value='checkbox2' required />
        <select required>
            <option value='option1'>option one</option>
            <option value='option2' selected='selected'>option two</option>
        </select>
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
<script>
var data={};
$('#myForm').submit(function(event){
    // cancels the form submission if it's invalid
    event.preventDefault();
var inputs = $('#myForm').find(':checked,:selected,:text,textarea').filter(function() {
    return $.trim( this.value ) != '';
});
var formField = inputs.map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get();

$.each(formField, function( index, value ) {
    data['credentialFields['+index+'].value']=value;
});$.ajax({ type : "POST",
        url : "restUrl",
        data : data
          });    

});


</script>
```